# aws-adfs is not a command - Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, unix, terminal, aws-cli

When I try to run `aws-adfs` commands on terminal, it displays as `aws-adfs` is not a command. I've installed `aws-cli`. Also on terminal able to get the aws version through the command. How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`aws-adfs` is another cli tool.
you need to install it from [aws-adfs](https://github.com/venth/aws-adfs).